# Hide navigation bar in view controller pushed from UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UIViewController` (let's call it **VC0**) in a `UINavigationController`. **VC0** makes use of a `UISearchDisplayController` to display results in a `UITableView` from a search. After the user selects a table cell from the search results, it pushes another `UIViewController` (call it **VC1**).

In both **VC0** and **VC1**, I have set `navigationBarHidden` to `YES`. However, when I select the table cell and **VC1** is pushed, I still see the navigation bar on top of **VC1** with a back button to **VC0**.

How do I permanently hide the navigation bar in **VC1**?

**Update:**

The navigation bar disappears if I put the following line in `viewDidAppear:`, but it is still visible before it is hidden.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

But if I put it in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:`, it doesn't work. Any reason why?

Comment: You want to hide Navigationbar on both ViewControllers?

Comment: @VivekMolkar Yes. I am able to hide it in VC0 but not in VC1.

Comment: How are you pushing VC1? push Segue?

Comment: @VivekMolkar nope, through the navigation controller.
`[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC1 animated:YES];`

Answer (score -1):

Make a simple **ViewController** as a name BaseViewController.
and make your both VC0 and VC1 is derived from BaseViewController. and simply set your `navigationBarHidden` to `YES` in BaseViewController.

this will applicable to VC0 and VC1 by simple one line of code.

1. `@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController`
2. `@interface VC0 : BaseViewController`
3. `@interface VC1 : BaseViewController`

like this

and BaseViewController's method

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
 }
```

Comment: Is there no other way to do it? I would preferably not want to change the structure of my view controllers.

Comment: then you have to write your  `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;` in each viewControllers **viewWillAppear** method.

Comment: It doesn't work, I still see the navigation bar in VC1.